# Setting an Image to a label in Qt

Tags: image, qt

I need to get a label image into a Qt Widget

I have tried putting a label on the widget then just on its properties on the right under text i selected `pixmap` and selected the image I wanted to use.

However when I run the program no image appears any ideas why this is?

I have also tried :

```
QLabel label("<img src='image.jpg' />");
label.show();
```

But had no luck do not think I was using it right

Comment: You can also do it modifying the style of the `QLabel` using `CSS` syntax.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Official way of "adding image to `QLabel`" provided by Nokia Corp. A `QPixmap` is used.

```
QLabel label;
QPixmap pixmap(":/path/to/your/image.jpg");
label.setPixmap(pixmap);
label.setMask(pixmap.mask());

label.show();
```

Comment: @AngryDuck Add your test code to the question.  The above code is correct, but the poster's example image dir is located in a resource file - have you just copied that and your image is not in a resource file?

Comment: @AngryDuck If you do it in the designer, does the designer at least show the image? If the application doesn't show it, then it might just be that the application cannot find the image (maybe it's a relative file path?). The easiest way to circumvent this (and pack all images with the application) is to use Qt's resource mechanism to include it directly with the application binary. This is the recommended aproach especially for such UI related images that always need to be present anyway (and usually don't span much memory either).

Comment: Yea it does show the image in the designer but not when the application is compiled, i have selected the image just from the drop down menu under pixmap in label properties. and the image is located im my project directory?

Comment: @AngryDuck *"the image is located im my project directory"* - But can the application find it there? Is it given as a relative path in the final setting code (that generated by the designer) and if yes, does this relative path match the working directory of the application when it is actually run (which doesn't neccessarily need to match the project directory exactly)? Seriously, I think this is just some directory mismatch. Like said, the easiest way would be to put this whole image into a Qt resource.

Comment: sorted it was a directory issue

Answer (score 2):

```
QIcon searchIcon = Icon::fromTheme("edit-find");
searchLabel->setPixmap( searchIcon.pixmap(16,16) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use Qt Style Sheets.

```
QLabel label;
label.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/images/assets/your.png)")
```